# Page is crashing if I call this method

Tags: jquery

I am using this method to answer a form randomly

```
  $('table').filter(function () {
      return ($(this).find('input').size() > 0);
  }).find('tr').each(function () {
      $(this).find('input').filter(function () {
          return (Math.round(Math.random()) == 1);
      }).each(function () {
          var typ = this.type;
          if (typ == 'checkbox' || typ == 'radio') {
              this.checked = true;
          }
          if (typ == 'select' || typ == 'select-one') {
              var value = $.map(this, function (elt, i) {
                  return $(elt).val();
              }).sort()[0];
              this.val(value);
          }
          if (typ = "text" || typ == "textarea") {
              $(this).val(Math.floor(Math.random() * 11));
          }
      });
  });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "page is crashing"?

Comment: Yes I can see what it's supposed be doing. What is it actually doing?

Comment: Does the mentioned "crashing" happen after you call `$('#forwardbutton').trigger('click');`, or earlier? Also please work on the code formatting - code is now hardly readable due to incorrect indents.

Comment: I am using Google chrome.. It is asking me to wait or kill the page.

Comment: @Sol: So if you get rid of `$('#forwardbutton').trigger('click');` line the page is not crashing, right? If yes, then remove it from the question to avoid confusion and make it easier to find the solution.

Comment: @Tadeck Yes, good suggestion. I have removed. Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing there's some sort of infinite loop, but I can't find it.  Can you produce a reproduction on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Your call to `$.map()` is iterating over all the properties of the current element, not over its children. Since DOM elements can have *many* properties, your performance problem might come from this.

Comment: Start commenting out bits and see when your problem goes away.  That should help you focus on what is actually the problem.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Yes your suggestion solved my problem. Could you please post it as a answer. Then I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
      if (typ == 'select' || typ == 'select-one') {
          var value = $.map(this, function (elt, i) {
              return $(elt).val();
          }).sort()[0];
          this.val(value);
      }
```

The [input](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.4.1) tag doesn´t have any `select` type and you can´t set the selected value this way `this.val(value);` as [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is a jQuery function, try `$(this).val(value)` (for inputs). You will have to change your slector to include `select` elements as well if you want to select on of its options.

```
      if (typ = "text" || typ == "textarea") {
          $(this).val(Math.floor(Math.random() * 11));
      }
```

By using a single `=` instead of `==` you are re declaring the variable making the condition `true`.

You should also be able to shorten the code by not using find() and each() so much. The following selector selectes `input` elements with in `tr` element within a `table` and then randomly filtering it as in your example.

```
$('table tr input').filter(function() { return (Math.round(Math.random()) == 1); })
```